# Django Satchmo DeserializationError when doing syncdb

Tags: python, django, yaml, satchmo, django-syncdb

When I do

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

it shows me this error:
DeserializationError:

```
could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/long'
```

I've installed and reinstalled pyyaml using pip and even rebuilt python from source...
Nothing chagned. Wjhat should I do?

Comment: I tried exactly same without problem now. (compiled Python 2.7.4 and [Satchmo Quick Install](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/quickstart.html), Django 1.4.x) Please write a traceback and Python and PyYAML vesion. (`python manage.py syncdb --traceback` and `pip freeze`)

Comment: Due to the lack of help, I've fixed the issue by **downgrading** back to the original Django and Satchmo versions that were used on the previous installation. It worked fine then, except that it shows the main page of the admin panel without any CSS (and the other admin pages work fine).

Comment: Due to lack of information it was not easy to help. Please, try to get a traceback by `python manage.py syncdb --traceback`. Write the version of Python, Django, Satchmo and Yaml. You can reproduce it without affecting the fixed system with `virtualenv --no-site-packages any_new_dir`, `source that_new_dir/bin/activate`, `pip install ...`